# Google Maps API - Custom controls shows without styling

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using the Google Maps API to shows the maps on my hybrid application,
Ex: http://www.google.com/maps/api/js?key=

It shows the maps correctly.  I have added the custom button on the map to handle new options. The custom button showed perfectly till Oct 14,2020 without any styling issues like other default buttons ("MAP / Satellite") on the map.

But Oct 15,2020 - The button shows without styling. Did Google change anything on the api? I am using the latest version of that.

"Sample" is button, but it shows without any styling, previously it shows as like other two option.

Code: I have created a `<div>` and added another `<div>` for "Sample" inside the parent div as google mentioned on the documentation. I did not change any logic on the code.

Added the button using below code,  it worked. but Oct 15 onwards it does not show the styling,

```
   let controlUI = document.createElement('div');
            controlUI.setAttribute('id', 'custommapmenu-wrapper');
            controlUI.style.cssText = 'margin-top: 10px; margin-left: -10px;';
            controlUI.index = 1;
            controlUI.innerHTML = '<div class="gm-style-mtc"> <div role="button" draggable="false" title="Show street map" > Sample</div></div>';

   let mapTypeControlOptions = {
                mapTypeControl: true,
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
                },
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(controlUI, mapTypeControlOptions);
```

[image]

I have tried with adding the version on the api point like below
http://www.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&&v=quarterly or
http://www.google.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&&v=3.41

It shows the button as expected.

If I have tried with out mention any version on the API, it considers as weekly so it take the 3.42.9. In the 3.42.9 version the UI styling logics has changed. It sets "Undefined" for the button styling.

Did Google MAP API change the logics.. please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Google changed the way they style the buttons (they aren't documented, so can change at any time).

They are now `<button>` elements with the style:

```
style="background: none padding-box rgb(255, 255, 255); display: table-cell; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 17px; text-transform: none; appearance: none; position: relative; cursor: pointer; user-select: none; direction: ltr; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; height: 40px; vertical-align: middle; color: rgb(86, 86, 86); font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px; border-top-right-radius: 2px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 4px -1px; min-width: 66px;"
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/sfn0x4jL/1/)

[image: screen shot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8,
  });
  let controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.setAttribute('id', 'custommapmenu-wrapper');
  controlUI.style.cssText = 'margin-top: 10px; margin-left: -10px;';
  controlUI.index = 1;
  controlUI.innerHTML = '<div class="gm-style-mtc"> <button draggable="false" title="Show street map" style="background: none padding-box rgb(255, 255, 255); display: table-cell; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 17px; text-transform: none; appearance: none; position: relative; cursor: pointer; user-select: none; direction: ltr; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; height: 40px; vertical-align: middle; color: rgb(86, 86, 86); font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; border-bottom-right-radius: 2px; border-top-right-radius: 2px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 4px -1px; min-width: 66px;" > Sample</div></div>';

  let mapTypeControlOptions = {
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(controlUI, mapTypeControlOptions);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```